# Height of plane after descending at two different speeds

Tags: algebra-precalculus

An Aircraft was flying at an altitude of 2500 metres. It descended for 2 minutes at a speed of 2.6 metres per second then descended for a further 3.2 minutes at 2.9 metres per second. Find the altitude of the aircraft after the descent

$$-120/2.6 - -192/2.9 = -348/7.5 - 499/7.5 = 151/7.5 = 20.13$$

I know this is completely wrong, any tips on how to find the final answer?

Comment: You should multiply the speed$\times$time.

Comment: $=2.6*120+2.9*192 (m)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It descended for 2 minutes at a speed of 2.6 metres per second

it means Height decrease in one second is 2.6 meters so  calculate how much it will descent after 2minutes=120 seconds

$$2.6*120\hspace{10pt}meters=312 meters$$

similarly, for the second descend $2.9*(192)=556.8 $ meters

$$total =312+556.8=868.8 \hspace{10pt}meters$$